# Classificação Automomática com critério de desempate

Tags: microsoft-excel, classificação

Boa tarde, utilizando a classificação automática do excel, é possível criar níveis e subníveis? Por exemplo, estou criando uma planilha de futebol e quero ordenar primeiramente por pontuação e caso haja empate, quem tem maior Saldo de gols fica na posição acima. Tentei utilizar os níveis de classificação, porém ele fica sempre alternando ou pega a maior pontuação ou maior saldo de gols. Gostaria que fosse primeiro pontuação e caso tenha empate, quem tem maior saldo de gols fique na frente.

Answer (score 2):

Boas,

penso que assim resolve o teu problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]